# CSS Inheritance and float:left issues

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am very new to CSS and have a few questions based on my code below:

1) Why does the bottom-border and background color cut off when i said the width= 100%?

2) Why does the second unordered list (with class "dropdown") within the first not inherit the elements declared to the parent unordered list (with class "tabs")?

3) Why does the first unordered list (with class "tabs") not appear horizontally when I run it in browser? I've tried using the 'float: left' and 'display: inline' lines but neither work, together or separately

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Random Web Page </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic styles test.cpp">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li>Pancakes</li>
                <li>Waffles</li>
                <li>Bacon</li>
                <li>Drinks
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li>Orange Juice</li>
                        <li>Milk</li>
                        <li>Water</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left = 0; 
    width = 100%; 
    background: red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs { 
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
 .dropdown {

}
```

Comment: deleting the 'width= 100%' doesn't fix the issue though

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable The navbar has `position: absolute` so `width: 100%` is actually necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your Syntax is wrong, its `width:100%`, not width = 100% :) same thing with left = 0
   It's always **attr:value** in CSS.
2. The second `ul` is not styled because u used `list-style:none` only on the class `.tabs`
   If u want to style all `ul`'s this way then u should use

   `ul {list-style:none}`
   or
   `.tabs, .dropdown {list-style:none}`
3. If u want the first `ul` horizontally u should use the `float:left` on the child-elements  `.tabs>li {float:left}`
   `.tabs>li` means u select ONLY direct `li`-elements from the `.tabs`-class element

Comment: They aren't using ordered lists they're using unordered lists. `ol -> ul`